# Dynamic page creation - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router, react-router-dom

let says I have 20 pages they are group with something like below:

```
Group one :
/education
/view-education

Group two :
/cft
/view-cft
/view-hisotry

Group 3:
...etc
```

I want to create a help page for each group, so that when I click the help button. It generated a support page for each group like:

```
/education/support
/cft/support
...etc
```

How do I do that with react-router?  I am thinking of using

```
import { useLocation, useHistory } from "react-router-dom"; 
history.push(`${pathname}`)
```

am i on the right track? any recommendation. I am stuck for few hours already tho

Comment: Use a [nested router](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/nesting) and [Link](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link) to `./support`?

Answer (score 0):

Could use a catch-all path, although the following was not tested:

```
<Route path="/support/:foo+">
  <MyPageThatWillLoadContent />
</Route>
```

As in the [docs of react router](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/path-string-string) it says the path can be:

```
path: string | string[]

Any valid URL path or array of paths that path-to-regexp@^1.7.0 understands.
```

And [`path-to-regexp` has an example](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp#one-or-more) where developer can match one or more params.

So in your component you should be able to get a parameter `foo`

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router';
....
const {foo} = useParams();
```

That will equal to `one/two/three` for a path `/support/one/two/three`. Then you could load assets based on that parameter.